# Are dreams a good place to begin world building?

Tags: alternate-worlds, worldbuilding-process

**I know this seems obvious but I wish to know**

I would like to say that I am quite a vivid dreamer, and it may seem truly obvious that dreams are where many worlds are born, such as Tolkien's *Lord Of The Rings* and *Harry Potter*, but I have always wanted to write a novel like this or multiple stories set in a world of my own creation. Could dreams help me out with this? Could they help me with names and help me with creating a vision to design this world for myself. I have dreamt of making of a world since I was a little kid, and have even lived them out with my friends in the woods, all coming from these dreams I had. So is it a good place to start?

Comment: Names are the easiest part -- there are many name generators free to use. Vision is harder, and yes, here dreams can help a lot -- both night dreams and day dreams. The hardest of all is materializing the vision, transforming it from an ethereal impression into a satisfying narrative, and here you get to choose between keeping the dream-like atmosphere (e.g., Stanislaw Lem's *Solaris*), developing it into a detailed world (e.g., Tolkien's Middle Earth or George R. R. Martin's *Song of Ice and Fire*), or finding a middle path like a very vivid dream  (e.g., Gustave Flaubert's *Salammbô*).

Comment: So have you had a dream that you want to turn into a world?  Or are you asking if it's possible for it to be viable?

Comment: Somebody (citation needed) started his most famous speech with "I have a dream", and he somehow managed to build a new world. However I am afraid your question, or hint for discussion, is misplaced here.

Comment: @L.Dutch, "somebody" was [Martin Luther King, Jr.](https://www.archives.gov/files/press/exhibits/dream-speech.pdf).

Comment: I regret that this question will be closed because, while you're asking a perfectly factual question about the source of imagination and creativity, you're not actually asking a question about how to build a world.  It's a thin line.  Nevertheless... YES, dreams are a perfectly good place to start.  [Check this out](https://www.theepochtimes.com/4-famous-authors-who-got-their-stories-in-dreams-stephen-king-stephanie-meyer-more_686149.html).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is closed as too opinion-based, to be honest. Every idea starts from somewhere, and no one can tell you whether one starting point is better than the other, because it honestly varies depending on your world.